# Removing space between columns in html table

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have an HTML table which is as following

Some of the code is below:

```html
<table>
  <tr>

    <td>
      <div style="width: 4.999999998%;" class="col-md-.6 col-sm-6">
        <div style="height: 103px; width:80px;" class="location-block">
          <div class="city-img">
            <img src="worldwide-location.png" class="img-responsive" alt="city">
            <div class="overlay-bg"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="city-dtl text-center">


            <a href="#" style="margin-left: -30px" class="btn btn-pink hidden-xs">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </td>


    <td>


      <div style=" width: 4.999999998%;" class="col-md-.6 col-sm-6">
        <div style="height: 50px; width:80px;" class="location-block">
          <div class="city-img">
            <img src="images/wedding-location/location-1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="city">
            <div class="overlay-bg"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="city-dtl text-center">


            <a href="#" style="margin-left: -30px;" class="btn btn-pink hidden-xs">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div style="height: 50px; width:80px; margin-top: -27px;" class="location-block">
          <div class="city-img">
            <img src="images/wedding-location/location-1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="city">
            <div class="overlay-bg"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="city-dtl text-center">

            <a href="#" style="margin-left: -30px;" class="btn btn-pink hidden-xs">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
    </td>
```

the table looks like the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsKkp.png)

As you can see the white space between each column, I am trying to reduce the white spaces between them, but this is not happening, I have tried padding-left and also gave cell spacing to the table, its not changing, can anyone tell me whats wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're using tables for visual layout along with inline styles and what looks like Bootstrap classes. This won't work. Tables aren't appropriate for layout. The Bootstrap styles and the User Agent Stylesheet (default CSS) are going to conflict with whatever you try to change.
I'm sure there's a way to do what you want to, but it can't be an answer to this question with this code. It probably needs to be in `DIV` blocks with child `IMG` elements. I recommend you ask a new question describing what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you decide to use Bootstrap grid you can avoid to use HTML table tag, and use a structure like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col margin-col">
    <div>Images and content 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col margin-col">
    <div>Images and content 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

usign a proper CSS rule like this to set padding (inside columns) and margin (outside columns):

```
.margin-col{
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```